# Graph API | Get facebook page members/likes

Tags: facebook, graph, members

I've got a question about the facebook graph api.

I have a example facebook page: https://www.facebook.com/pages/TheBestCompany/250721784993387

And i want to get the images from all the people that liked that page.

I've found on this site that it is **not** possible to find the people that liked a external page.  but thats not the case?

I hope to hear from you people:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that!

Have a look at the facebook api: [graph api pages](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/). You can get the count of likes for a page, but there is no connection to the people who like it. Furthermore, if you would know the facebook ids of these users, you would need the user_photos permission.

Comment: and with fql? maybe thats an option

Answer (score 0):

[Like button reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like) lists the options.

I don't know if 'show faces' is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thats what i'am looking for indeed i only need the faces as a array in javascript so i can play with the position etc.